# Setting Disk Quota for IIS Account (ApplicationPoolIdentity)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, ntfs

My ultimate goal is to effect a disk quota for files uploaded via a web application running on IIS.

I can probably do this by simply creating a special account under which the application runs, and then imposing a disk quota against that account.

But, it looks like I should instead be doing this against the “**ApplicationPoolIdentity**” for the app pool in question; however, I don't see a way to do this using the ordinary GUI tools for creating disk quotas.

So, how can we create NTFS quotas against App Pool virtual accounts?